# convert two number to a range

Tags: vba, excel

I am going create a macro to convert two number to a range, e.g.

On excel cell `A1` and `A2`, I input integer `1` and `5` respectively. The output will look like:

```
A3 1
A4 2
A5 3
A6 4
A7 5
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? If you have not tried anything then you might want to record a macro?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this without even using macros :)

1. in `A3` type your first number.
2. On the `Home` tab go to the `Editing` section > `Fill` > `Series...` 
   [image]
3. Choose to have your series populated in `Columns`. Choose a stop value of 20 (or whatever)
   [image]
4. Click OK

Now you will have a series of numbers 1-20 going down starting in Cell `A3`.

You can change your step value so that each number is incremented by 1, or 2 or 3 or whatever. You can also fill in rows instead of columns.

If you need it *more* automated than that just do all of that while recording a macro and see what it does then change the VBA to suit you more specific needs/come back here with some code to get advice on.

Answer (score 0):

The Below COde will read the Content from the A1 and A2. According to the range it will display the result in the A series only.

```
enter code here

For i = Cells(1, 1) To Cells(1, 2)
 Cells(1, i + 2) = i
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks! Finally, I use VBA to complete the task. And now I want to add prefix to each number in the cell. e.g. 001 -> abc-001. How can I do that? Below is the vba I used to create a series of number:                                                                                                                                                                                                            ActiveCell.Value = InputBox("first number")
 Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, Step:=1, Stop:=InputBox("last number"), Trend:=False

Comment: When you want o do in that ways its not possible to add the abc in front of them. If you use the code mentioned above then u can append abc in front of the i . it will work.